# mg_send_response_line() in mongoose not working

Tags: c, http, mongoose

I am trying to develop a server application using mongoose C library. In the initial stage of the my try, I am stuck at sending a response for an HTTP request.  I am trying to send a simple response of `status 200` using following line of code:

```
 mg_send_response_line(nc, 200, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 printf("Response sent...\n");
```

But the response is not received to the client(Postman or web-browser). 
There is no error, and even the `printf line of Response sent is printed`.
As against to this, following lines are getting executed successfully:

```
 mg_http_send_error(nc,404, "Fatal Error!"); // I get this error at client side.
```

The basic simplest_web_server also works fine. Why is my single line of code sending response failing. I am not able to understand/ debug this.

Regards,

Neeraj.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there is no content length or transfer encoding specified for the HTTP response and the server does not close the connection so the client hangs waiting for the response.

If you look through the [source code](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/master/mongoose.c), you will see that in `mg_http_send_error()`, the `MG_F_SEND_AND_CLOSE` flag is set but it is not set within `mg_send_response_line()` (though, like you, I assumed that this would be handled by the function).

To fix the issue in your context,

```
mg_send_response_line(nc, 200, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
printf("Response sent...\n");
nc->flag |= MG_F_SEND_AND_CLOSE;
```